# Trace morphism in Lipman's "Dualizing sheaves, differentials and residues on algebraic varieties".

Tags: algebraic-geometry, duality-theorems, projective-varieties

Let $f: V \to W$ be a finite surjective morphism of varieties, with $W$ proper and normal. Does there exist a trace map
$$ \operatorname{trace}\colon f_* \mathcal O_V \to \mathcal O_W? $$

I know that such a thing exists if $f$ is etalé, or (more generally) finite and flat. Does normality of $W$ help here?

Lipman seems to assume the existence in his exposition *Dualizing sheaves, differentials, and residues on algebraic varieties*, but doesn't explain it further.
[image: Excerpt from Lipman's exposition]

In general, if $A \subset B$ is a finite ring extension, there is a finite fileld extension $K \subset L$ of fraction fields, and a [trace map](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BIE) $\operatorname{trace}: L \to K$. I guess one wants to restrict this to $B$ and hopes it ends up in $A$?

I find it hard to find examples where $f$ is not finite and flat, but [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_morphism#cite_ref-34),

$$\mathbb C[x^2, xy, y^2] \subset \mathbb C[x,y]$$

gives an example where $X$ is regular, $Y$ is normal, but $f$ is not flat. However, considering the extension of quotient fields $K \subset L$ one sees that $L = K(x)$, and $x$ has degree $2$. The trace mapping is then given by
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{trace}: L & \to K \\
1 & \mapsto \operatorname{trace} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 2 \\
x & \mapsto \operatorname{trace}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & x^2 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0 \\
y & \mapsto \operatorname{trace}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & xy \\ \frac{xy}{x^2} & 0 \end{pmatrix} = 0.
\end{align*}
Since $\mathbb C[x,y]$ is generated by $x,y$ as a $\mathbb C[x^2, xy, y^2]$-module, we see indeed that the trace morphism descends to a morphism
$$ \mathbb C[x,y] \to \mathbb C[x^2, xy, y^2].$$

Are there examples where the trace map does not descend?

Comment: @AshwinIyengar Yes, thanks for pointing this out. I didn't find it with the search.